# Arduino Speaker making long continuous noise

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-uno, speaker

Arduino speaker seems not to be working according to my code. It is not shutting off the sound.

I am trying to run the code below. However, when I press the button all I get is one long, continuous sound. When I change the frequency, the tone also changes, so it appears to be reading the frequency correctly, but it wont change the frequency when I adjust the potentiometer.

I also tried running a smaller piece of code where it should only play a sound for 1 second. When I ran the code, the speaker had the same result: the speaker made one sound and wouldn't stop until I unplugged the Arduino.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

```
board = PyMata3(com_port="com5")
pot = Pot(board, PIN_POT, 10) 
spkr = Speaker(board, PIN_SPEAKER)
led = Led(board, PIN_LED0)
button = Button(board, PIN_SW0, activeLevel=0, internalPull=1)

while True:
    if button.isPressed():
        if pot.fraction() < 0.3:
            spkr.play(50)
        if 0.3 <= pot.fraction() < 0.65:
            spkr.play(100)
        if 0.65 <= pot.fraction() <= 1.0:
            spkr.play(200)
```

I'd expect the speaker to change frequency with the adjustment of the potentiometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just called play method. where is the stop / pause ?

Comment: Yup. That’s was it. Thanks.